# Complexity comparision of SIMD based algorithm implemenation

Tags: algorithm, simd

I am just curious to know, what is the way to measure the complexity of an algorithm implemented by two different SIMD say SSE3 and CUDA. Normally we compare algorithm complexity with Big-O notation. Is there any such way to compare  runtime improvement with SIMD ?

If somebody ask how much an algorithm will improve if you run it on GPU. Can you measure it theoretically ? without running the benchmark on both CPU and GPU. ?

Note: I understand what Big-O is . So, all I want to know is how SSE3 performs compared to CUDA or the CPU based implementation for the same algorithm without raw bench-marking

Answer (score 3):

Big-O notation is, for the most part, inapplicable to CPU instructions.

Instructions belong to the realm of the lowly hardware, the impure flesh of the computer.  Computer science does not concern itself with such crude notions.

<sub>(Actually, the term "Computer Science" is a misnomer.  There is this widely circulated quote that "Computer science is no more about computers than astronomy is about telescopes."  It is misattributed to Edsger Dijkstra, but actually it originates from Michael R. Fellows, read about it here: https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Computer_science)</sub>

In any case, if you insist on thinking of algorithms as being executed by CPU instructions, and if you also insist on reasoning about the run-time complexity of instructions, then you have to think of memory accesses.

You need to first come up with some "unit of work" that is comparable between SSE3 and CUDA, and then you need to setup some mechanism so that you can measure

- how the number of memory accesses of SSE3 increases in relation to the amount of work to do, and
- how the number of memory accesses of CUDA increases in relation to the same amount of work to do.

That would be quite hard to accomplish, and my guess would be that the results would be quite linear, meaning that no matter which one takes more or less memory accesses, the number of accesses would change linearly with respect to the amount of work to do, in both cases.

Comment: So If I ask you, that how much an algorithm will improve if you run it on GPU. Can you measure it theoretically ? without running the benchmark on both CPU and GPU. ?

Comment: Algorithms do not improve depending on where you run them.  Never mind the unfortunate wording of your question, it goes even deeper than that: The run-time complexity of an algorithm does not improve depending on where you run it.

Comment: I can understand with big-oh we can't measure it. And that's fine, then when we will move an to an SIMD or GPU based implementation how we are gonna show that it will run faster wrt the serial execution on cpu theoretically.  And even though we can show that we are doing parallel execution how to represent performance comparison of two different kind of SIMD implementation without raw benchmarks. Thanks

Comment: Right.  I am glad we got big-oh out of the way.  So, all you want to know is how SSE3 performs compared to CUDA.  This is a technical quest, not a scientific one.  So, the answer to that is: I don't know of any way other than raw benchmarks.  You could read the technical manuals of the manufacturers and try to reason from their descriptions, but I would not put much weight in that.

Comment: "So, all you want to know is how SSE3 performs compared to CUDA/CPU based implementation"- Yes , I am looking for the answer for this question only. And thanks for your explanation.

Comment: In general, the performance is going to depend on how efficiently you use the instruction set, @RBanerjee. It's just like the eternal debate about whether C++ or Java is faster. Almost always, the faster/better one is the one that the programmer is most familiar with, because it's in that one that he writes the best, most correct code. Same thing for ISAs. If you really wanted to do a fair test, you'd pick a general problem (something common that both ISAs should be expected to do well, like maybe encryption), have experts in both ISAs write tests, and then compare them. Too broad for SO.

Answer (score 2):

Big-O generally speaks about how an algorithm scales as the number of items considered, *N*, grows.

So, for an *O(N)* algorithm, if you have 10 times the data, you expect roughly 10 times the run-time. If you have an *O(n log₂ n)* algorithm, 10 times the data gives you ~33x more work.

Roughly speaking, CUDA and GPUs parallelize operations across *p* cores. The total work done is then given by `W=pt`, where *p* is the number of cores and `t` the time complexity of each core's operation. You could, for instance, sort *N* items using *√N* processors each doing *O(√N log N)* work. The total time complexity of the algorithm is still *O(N log N)*, but the algorithm is thought of as "work-efficient" because its total time complexity is the same (or less than) the best known serial algorithm. So Big-O analysis *can* tell you something about how algorithms run in parallel environments.

However, it is not the tool you are looking for. Big-O is for talking about how algorithms *scale*: it can't tell us how an algorithm will perform on different hardware.

For a theoretical approach to performance, you'll want to look into [Amdahl's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law) and [Gustafson's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gustafson%27s_law), which provide simple metrics of how much improvement we can expected in programs when their resources are increased. They both boil down to acknowledging that the total increase in speed is a function of the portion of the program we can speed up and the amount we can speed it up by.

Can you do better than that? Yes. There are more sophisticated models you can use to determine how your code might perform in different environments, looking into the [roofline model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roofline_model) ([alternative link](https://crd.lbl.gov/departments/computer-science/PAR/research/roofline/)) might get you started.

Beyond this, your question gets too specific to be answered well here. Running the benchmarks is likely to be your personal best option.

Answer (score 1):

Some of the answers (and maybe your question) reflect basic misconceptions about Big-O.  `O(f(n))` is just a *classification of mathematical functions*. It has nothing to do *a priori* with run time or anything else.  [The definition of big-O](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) makes this pretty clear.

With the right mathematical machinery, sure, what you ask is certainly possible.

To use big-O in the context of algorithms, you must first describe the *function that you're classifying*.  A classical example is sorting algorithms. Here a function frequently used is the *number of comparisons* `f(n)` needed to sort a list of given length `n`. When we say (rather imprecisely) that a sorting algorithm is `O(n log n)`, we're usually saying that when `n` is big enough, the number of comparisons needed to sort is capped by `K n log(n)` where `K` is some positive constant.

You can also use big-O in the context of *run time*, but you must also stipulate a formal machine model. This is a mathematically precise abstraction of a real machine. There are many of these. For many purposes that *don't* involve parallel processing, the [Word RAM](http://www2.ift.ulaval.ca/~quimper/publications/wordram_poster.pdf) or [Real RAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_RAM) is used, but there are other options.

When we say "an algorithm is `O(g(n))`", what we really mean, most of the time, is "the number of Word RAM clock cycles needed to run the algorithm on input of size `n` is capped by `K g(n)` for some constant `K`, given that `n` is large enough.

That is, with an abstract machine model in hand, the function classified by big-O is just the number of clock cycles of the abstract machine as a function of input size.

For SIMD computation, the [PRAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_random-access_machine) is one commonly used abstract machine model. As all abstract machine models, it makes simplifying assumptions. For example, both memory size and number of processors are unlimited. It also allows for different strategies to resolve memory contention among processors. Just as for the Word RAM, big-O performance of algorithms running on a PRAM are statements about the number of clock cycles needed with respect to input size.

[There has been some work on abstract models of GPUs](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/d8c0/179df4bc7bb9c7d7a2e7347c125d0935446d.pdf) that allow big O to approximate useful functions describing algorithm performance. It remains a topic of research.

So comparing sequential vs. parallel performance or parallel performance on different architectures is a matter of choosing the right abstract models, describing a program for each that implements the algorithm you're interested in, then comparing big-O descriptions of the number of clock cycle each requires.

Answer (score 0):

Using SIMD/SSE3 does not change Big-O complexity, because it executes constant number (upto 16) operations.

```
 O(Function(N)/Const) === O(Function(N))
```

The same is true for CUDA, despite of thousand cores working (if we ignore different memory access model and CUDA implementation does not utilize another algorithm)

Comment: So If I ask you, that how much an algorithm will improve if you run it on GPU. Can you measure it theoretically ? without running the benchmark on both CPU and GPU. ?

Comment: We can expect that when input size changes, both implementations times change in similar manner (until another factors take place)